# index_max not a member of arma in RcppArmadillo

Tags: rcpp

When I compile the following code in `Rstudio` , which is an example in the armadillo documentation,  I get a message of error:

**Code:**

```
arma::vec   v = arma::randu<arma::vec>(10);
arma::uword i = arma::index_max(v);
```

The error message is:

> 'index_max' is not a member of 'arma'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version?

There was an (upstream) oversight in 0.7.200.2.0 so maybe try 0.7.300.1.0 from the [RcppCore drat repo](http://rcppcore.github.io/drat/) as discussed in [this announcement on rcpp-devel](http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/rcpp-devel/2016-July/009318.html).

Comment: Yes, I was using 0.7.200.2.0 but installed the 0.7.300.1.0 and now it works, thanks. I used the drat library, and then typed the command drat:::add("RcppCore")  in Rstudio. Then I looked for updates within the Rstudio 'Tools menu' and chose yes when asked "Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?"

Comment: It is a bug (in Armadillo) but you are only the second known case where someone was bitten.

Comment: So ... if it helped, feel free to "accept" (click on tickmark) and/or "up-vote" (click on triangle pointing up).  That's how StackOverflow works.  You get points for accepting an answer too.